# Create PayPal Payment to account through email in order form

Tags: node.js, npm, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Currently, I'm using the [paypal-rest-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-rest-sdk) for node.js and am using [`paypal.payment.create()`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal.js). However, for this, it's required that the seller have a business account as you need to enter a token and Id from an application on the developer's page.

I've seen in other methods that a seller uses their email for customers to pay through in an order/payment method - instead of using the token and Ids.

---

To elaborate further, currently I have to use

```js
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
paypal.configure({
    'mode': 'live', //sandbox or live
    'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
    'client_secret': 'CLIENT_SECRET'
});
```

However, in the json object that used is there a way to have an account email to pay to. For example

```
var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "business": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": `return`,
        "cancel_url": `cancel`
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": itemsList
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": total.toFixed(2),
            "details": {
                "subtotal": subPrice.toFixed(2).toString(),
                "tax": "0.00",
                "shipping": "0.00",
                "discount": sortedDiscount.toFixed(2),
            }
        },
        "description": `Store payment.`
    }]
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own credentials and specify a `payee` in the request, as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/

Since you are using the deprecated PayPal-Node-SDK and the deprecated v1/payments API, the parameter name will be transactions[0]->payee, as seen in the API reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#definition-transaction

(For new integrations, you should be using the current Checkout-NodeJS-SDK and v2/checkout/orders API instead)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. However, does this allow for me to not have to specify the CLEINT information and just use the email?

Comment: I didn't fully specify that part of the post. It's hard to explain in a way

Comment: To specify a different receiver when you create a payment or order, add the payee object to the transaction payload and include the email_address or merchant_id of the account to receive the payment.

Comment: Understood, But does this allow me to not specify `'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID','client_secret': 'CLIENT_SECRET'` in the `paypal.configure`. Looking for a solution as I can't create applications without a business account.

Comment: Use your own credentials. If your account isn't of type business, upgrade it.